# AWS S3 Presigned URLs Policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

Currently working on a project that involves what is essentially an online gallery stored on AWS S3. The current process in question is that the frontend webpage sends a request for an API service hosted on EC2, which then returns with a presigned URL. The service will be using Go, with aws-sdk-go-v2.

The URL is time limited, set as a PUT object type. Unfortunately I haven't figured out how to limit the other aspects of the file that will be uploaded yet. Ideally, the URL should be limited in what it can accept, IE images only.

My searchs around have come up with mixed results, saying both it's possible, not possible, or just outright not mentioned for what I'm doing.

There's plenty of answers regarding setting a POST/PUT policy, but I they're either for the V1 SDK, or just outright a different language. [This answer here even has a few libraries that does it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377782/how-to-do-a-pre-signed-post-upload-to-aws-s3-in-go), but I don't want to resort to using that yet since it requires access keys to be placed in the code, or somewhere in the environment (Trying to reap the benefits of EC2's IAM role automating the process).

Anyone know if this is still a thing on V2 of the SDK? I kinda want to keep it on V2 of the SDK just for the sake of consistency.

EDIT: Almost forgot. I saw that it was possible for S3 to follow a link upon upload completion as well. Is this still possible? Would be great as a verification that something was uploaded so that it could be logged.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to validate the filename through the your backend API before returning the PreSigned PUT URL. And a less sequre but can be good, is to validate the file content in the frontend client.

Comment: Frontend validation is a must. Tho at this rate I think I might as well have the file relayed to the backend API before passing to S3. EC2 bandwidth is not that expensive appearantly. But yeah, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately have not discovered a way to restrict uploads via the Content-Type, but I have found a few tricks that might help you.

First, while this is a bit of a sledgehammer when you might want a scalpel, you can apply a bucket policy to restrict by filename. This example from [AWS Knowledge Center](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-allow-certain-file-types/) only allows a few image types.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/exampleuser"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*.jpg",
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*.png",
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*.gif"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "NotResource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*.jpg",
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*.png",
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*.gif"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Second, you can [automatically trigger a Lambda function after the file is uploaded](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html). With this method, you can inspect anything about the file you want after it is uploaded. This is generally my preferred approach, but the problem with it is there's not really any immediate feedback the file was invalid.

My last option requires the client to do some more work, and it's what I used most recently. If you are uploading very large files, S3 requires you to use [multipart uploads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html). This isn't multipart like an HTML form; this is breaking the file up into chunks and uploading each of them. If your file is sufficiently small--I think the limit is 5GB, you can just do a single part. Once all the parts are uploaded, you must make another call to your server that finalizes the upload with S3. This is where you can add some validation of the file and respond to the client while they're still on the upload page.

Comment: I'd be a little concerned if someone was uploading a 5GB image, lol.

File-extension is not exactly what I was hoping for, but it would work. The Lamda function's good tho, since I do need a verification system to notify that something's done uploading. 

Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I would avoid front end validation and put the filtering on the HTML Input (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#accept). The server validation is really what will matter.